# JavaScript canvas charting library for line chart with specific features

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, charts

I am trying to create a HTML5 canvas (can also be SVG or vector based) line chart with following requirements.

- Ability to shade between two lines when one line is greater than the other.(as shown in the figure below).
  [image: Rough Drawing]
- Ability to draw texture layers

```
-------------------------------------------------------
texture1 10% width, texture2 90% width
-------------------------------------------------------
texture1 20% width, texture2 80% width
-------------------------------------------------------
..
.. and so on
-------------------------------------------------------
```

- Ability to draw gradient chart

```
-------------------------------------------------------
color1 20% color2 10% color3 40% color4 30%
-------------------------------------------------------
color1 20% color2 30% color3 30% color4 20%
-------------------------------------------------------
..
.. and so on
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any javascript library that can do all of them? If not, are there any libraries that can so each of them individually. If no open-source solutions are available, please suggest good paid libraries.

I am using flot charts at present, which have all the features that I want except the first and third points mentioned above.

Comment: This seem very specialized and you will probably have to make something from scratch. In any case, asking for recommendations of libraries is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thank you Ken. I will not post these sort of questions in future. I have spent a day trying to find a library to suit our needs. Yes, we are planning to build it from scratch but just before that we want to know whether there are any libraries which can do this as we are running against time. :)

Answer (score 4):

No reason to do anything from scratch! Gradients are a standard feature in the [ZingChart charting library](http://www.zingchart.com/) and you can easily do [range based fill](http://www.zingchart.com/playground/run/54fa05501a206) with [rules](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/rules/).

As for the texture layers, do you mind clarifying? Could you provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Disclaimer: I'm on the ZingChart team, here to answer any questions about implementation you might have.